# Flutter - Wait setState in FutureBuilder then load component

Tags: flutter

I´m trying something like that. Load the service in Future Builder, set Text Field values and then write the component.

```
 final data = FutureBuilder(
            future: DatameterService.getMapData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                setState(() {
                  calleController.text = snapshot.data.calle;
                  paisController.text = snapshot.data.pais;
                  provinciaController.text = snapshot.data.provincia;
                  poblacionController.text = snapshot.data.poblacion;
                  postalController.text = snapshot.data.postal;
                });
                return form;
              } else {
                return indicator;
              }
```

But return

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

So the question is: How can fill TextField inputs values using FutureBuilder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never call `setState` in build, and the reason is simple: setState causes a build, and build calls setState - you're in an infinite loop. That's why the engine tells you explicitly that you shouldn't try to do this.

In fact, you should not be doing any business logic inside build. From your code, it looks like you wanna load some data when the page appears and set some initial fields to your `TextField`s. I don't think you want to be using a `FutureBuilder` here, since you have a `StatefulWidget`. Instead, you can move the future out of the build and have it be called in `initState`.

Something like this:

```dart
class _MyState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Map<String, dynamic> _data;
  bool _loading;
  TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // start fetching
    _loading = true;
    _data = {};
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    getData().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        _data = data;
        _loading = false;
        _controller.text = _data['text'];
      });
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // handle loading vs. not loading
    if (_loading) return CircularProgressIndicator();
    return Container(
      // the rest of your code
    );
  }
}
```

You don't really even need to store `_data` but it could be useful for resetting the forms or something.

Comment: The approach I have been looking for since FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder were not suitable for me

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to understand what a `FutureBuilder` to call that way.
A `FutureBuilder` has a child `future:` to which you assign an asynchronous method which has `.then` attached to it. '.then' will be called once the asynchronous process completes.

Coming to the answer, you can call setState this way.

```
myFutureMethod.then((value) => {
      setState(() {
        value = true;
      })
    });
```